# What happens when two different threads SwitchToFiber to the same fiber?

Tags: winapi

What happens when two different threads at the same time call SwitchToFiber() using the same fiber addresses to switch to?

```
void Thread1() { SwitchToFiber(fiberA); }
void Thread2() { SwitchToFiber(fiberA); }
```

Is this illegal?

Comment: crash. fiber this is stack. if 2 threads will be use the same stack - crash. this is wrong and illegal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-switchtofiber) clearly states:

> The `SwitchToFiber` function saves the state information of the current fiber and restores the state of the specified fiber. **You can call `SwitchToFiber` with the address of a fiber created by a different thread**. To do this, you must have the address returned to the other thread when it called `CreateFiber` and **you must use proper synchronization**.

If you don't synchronize your threads to serialize switching of fibers across thread boundaries, you run into **undefined behavior** territory, so *anything* could happen.

Comment: This seems a correct interpretation by consensus and that its base behaviour must be to blindly switch stacks, but I don't think the documentation is actually that clear here.  As continuing to run the existing fibre for one of threads could be seen as viable implementation.